# Regular Expression for removing 1, but not 2 Newlines

Tags: regex

I have a mostly ascii data file (10+ gigs) that uses byte x03 instead of newline.

As a result, I can't use general command line tools (grep, sed, etc) without first sending the file through fold.

Currently I'm doing this, folding and replacing x03 with 2 newlines:

**fold  original.dat | sed 's/\x03/\n\n/g' > withLinebreaks.dat**

However, now the lines broken up with extra newlines, making it difficult to search.

How can I remove all the extra newlines added by fold?
I need some way to remove all the newlines that occur singly, or newlines that are not the first byte of a line (ie all the newlines that should stay are on their own line)

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, you want to remove newlines when 2 are consecutive? No? I mean, all newlines are the first byte of a line, or the last one of the previous one if you will, and if they occur singly then how can a script know they're wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you need fold?  It seems like `sed 's/\x03/\n/g' original.dat > withLinebreak.dat` would do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may do what you are looking for in a single step:

```
tr '\3' '\n' < original.dat > withLinebreak.dat
```

Comment: This works, and seems to be faster than the original fold->sed combo.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
fold original.dat | sed 's/\x03/\n\n/g' | sed 's/\n\n/\n/g' > withLinebreaks.dat
```

Comment: Didn't work, I think the problem is that everything sed is line based, so it never sees \n\n.
For an easy example:

This is line 1.\n
This is line 2.\n
\n\n
This is line 3.\n